# Cubemap video 360 viewer?

Tags: youtube, viewer

I can upload equirectangular video to Youtube to view 360 video.
Right now, I have created a cubemap video, however Youtube is not supported yet.
If there any viewer for cubemap 360 video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, Whirligig plays cubemap video very well and it's free!

Answer (score 0):

A little late reply :)

GoPro VR Player 2.3 has started supporting Facebook 360 video. One has to choose the projection type of the video from Input > Projection menu option.

http://www.kolor.com/2017/03/29/360-video-player-gopro-vr-player-2-3-beta-1/